# stop repeat the actions on the page after submit the form

Tags: php, forms

Stop repeat the actions on the page after submit the form
I made this "sign in" form and made a error messages to appear if the fields is empty and other error messages.

my request is:
After the "sign in" fails how to stop the fields from resubmit the values again when hit F5 or reload the page.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include "config/config.php";
include "includes/functions/check.php";

$userName = $passWord = "";
$userNameErr = $passWordErr = $loginErr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $userNameErr = "User name is required";

    } else {
        $userName = check_input($_POST['user_name']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $userName)) {
            $userNameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $passWordErr = "Password is required";
    } else {
        $passWord = check_input($_POST['password']);
    }

    $loginUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hired_person_info WHERE user_name=? AND password=?");
    $loginUser->bind_param('ss', $userName, $passWord);
    if ($loginUser->execute()) {
        $results = $loginUser->get_result();
        if ($results->num_rows == 1) {
            $row = $results->fetch_object();
            $_SESSION['name'] = $row->full_name;
            $_SESSION['log'] = 1;
            print_r($_SESSION);
            header("Location:?pid=4");
        } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $loginErr = "Invalid Login Information";
        }
    }
}
ob_flush()
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Administration Panel</title>
    <link href="../css/adminStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="head" class="header_height"></h1>

<div class="contentLogin">
    <div class="login_bg">
        <div id="header">
            <p>login</p>
        </div>
        <div id="form">
            <?php
            echo $loginErr;
            ?>

            <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

                <label for="user_name" class="text_login">User name</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" value="<?php echo $userName ?>">
                <?php echo $userNameErr; ?>
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="password" class="text_login">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                <?php echo $passWordErr; ?>
                <br/>

                <div id="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){` try using the post name of your submit button. So the condition will be as follows,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

}
```

Within this you can put all your codes. I am not telling that the condition you have used is wrong, but it may create conflict when you will put another form in the same page.

And after your operation completed, success or fail, does not matter just unset the post variable.

```
unset($_POST);
```

To completely avoid the resend functionality you need to redirect your page to the same page once. For that just save your error message in session and redirect to login page again. Then checking if session value for message exists then display your message.